# Failed to deserialize Avro record - Apache flink SQL CLI

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-sql

I'm publishing avro serialized data to kafka topic and then trying to create Flink table from the topic via SQL CLI interface. I'm able to create the topic but not able to view the topic data after executing SQL  `SELECT` statement. Howver, I'm able to deserialize and print the published data using Simple kafka consumer. Getting this error on the SQL CLI:

```
Flink SQL> SELECT * FROM test_flink2;
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -3 out of bounds for length 2
```

**Table Creation**

```
Flink SQL> CREATE TABLE test_flink2 (
> `name` STRING,
> `address` STRING)
> WITH (
> 'connector' = 'kafka',
> 'topic' = 'test_flink2',
> 'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
> 'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'krypton04.psc:9092',
> 'format' = 'avro');
[INFO] Table has been created.
```

**Table Definition**

```
Flink SQL> DESC test_flink2;
+---------+--------+------+-----+--------+-----------+
|    name |   type | null | key | extras | watermark |
+---------+--------+------+-----+--------+-----------+
|    name | STRING | true |     |        |           |
| address | STRING | true |     |        |           |
+---------+--------+------+-----+--------+-----------+
2 rows in set
```

**Avro schema**

```
{
  "name": "MyClass",
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "myns",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "address",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Message value** (Message key is None)

```
    value = {'name' : 'vikram',
            'address' : 'hyd'}
```

I'm sending this same message value continuously using Simple kafka producer to topic `test_flink2`

**Kafka topic Description**

```
Topic: reddyvel_test_flink2 PartitionCount: 1   ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs: 
    Topic: reddyvel_test_flink2 Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,4,5 Isr: 1,4,5
```

**Full Error log**

From `flink-*-sql-client-*.log`

```
2021-02-05 09:10:01,351 WARN  org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient                  [] - Could not execute SQL statement.
org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.SqlExecutionException: Error while retrieving result.
        at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.result.CollectStreamResult.lambda$startRetrieval$0(CollectStreamResult.java:96) ~[flink-sql-client_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:610) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:840) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:479) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 583e8c2eb20eb8d8bdedba04673bb297)
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:125) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$pollResourceAsync$22(RestClusterClient.java:665) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:394) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:610) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1085) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 583e8c2eb20eb8d8bdedba04673bb297)
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:125) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$pollResourceAsync$22(RestClusterClient.java:665) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:394) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:610) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1085) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:123) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$pollResourceAsync$22(RestClusterClient.java:665) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:394) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:610) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1085) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:118) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:80) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:233) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:224) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:215) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:665) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:89) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:447) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:306) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
 at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:213) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:77) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:159) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deserialize Avro record.
        at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.java:104) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.java:44) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema.deserialize(DeserializationSchema.java:82) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.table.DynamicKafkaDeserializationSchema.deserialize(DynamicKafkaDeserializationSchema.java:113) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaFetcher.partitionConsumerRecordsHandler(KafkaFetcher.java:177) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaFetcher.runFetchLoop(KafkaFetcher.java:137) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:761) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:110) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:66) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:241) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -3 out of bounds for length 2
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Symbol$Alternative.getSymbol(Symbol.java:460) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:283) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:187) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:259) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:247) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroDeserializationSchema.java:137) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.java:101) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.java:44) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema.deserialize(DeserializationSchema.java:82) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.table.DynamicKafkaDeserializationSchema.deserialize(DynamicKafkaDeserializationSchema.java:113) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaFetcher.partitionConsumerRecordsHandler(KafkaFetcher.java:177) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaFetcher.runFetchLoop(KafkaFetcher.java:137) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:761) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:110) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:66) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:241) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
```

I'm not able to figure out the cause of the issue here.

Thanks.

Comment: How was the data produced? If you're using the Confluent tools, you need to use Flink's Confluent Avro Deserializer

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm using confluent kafka python API for sending messages. Using `MessageSerializer` to serialize the messages (https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/56aa46b73bdd0fbd1b29d13008a840f43fa56a39/src/confluent_kafka/avro/serializer/message_serializer.py#L63)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> using confluent kafka python API for sending message

Then you must use Flink's [Confluent Avro deserializer](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/formats/avro-confluent.html)

Your error is because you're trying to consume plain Avro, which requires the schema to be part of the message (it can't find it, so throws array out of bounds)

Comment: But we are not using confluent schema registry for loading schemas. We have implemented our own File based schema registry that loads avro schemas from file system. So [confluent avro deserializer](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/formats/avro-confluent.html) may not work as it requires confluent schema registry url. Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: The Python class you linked to requires a Schema Registry, specifically, the Confluent implementation. If you have something different, then you need to write the appropriate implementation in Flink's API or embed the schema in the message so that standard Avro deserializers can read it

Comment: @Markiv were you able to solve this?